# Sound Juicer doesn't respect Lame's codec settings when ripping CDs

Tags: sound, mp3, cd-ripping, lame

Using **Sound Juicer** I am able to rip CDs very conveniently. I would like to rip them in about 256 kbit/s variable bitrate. To accomplish this I have defined the settings for mp3 in `gnome-audio-profiles-properties` (from [gnome-media-profiles [image: Install gnome-media-profiles]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-media-profiles)) as follows:

```
audio/x-raw-int,rate=44100,channels=2 ! lame name=enc mode=0 vbr-quality=0 ! id3v2mux
```

where `vbr-quality=0` should give me a variable bitrate averaging 245 kbit/s. The resulting files however always say they are in 128 kbit/s.

When I change `vbr-quality` from 6 to 0 all resulting files differ in exactly 1 Byte only when comparing them with `cmp file1.mp3 file2.mp3`. This means vbr-quality settings have **no effect** here.

Comment: Would you please put the complete path to the option in gconf-editor? I'm not finding gnome-audio-profiles-properties

Comment: @neves: it is an application... see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting for Lame are incomplete. We will have to define VBR mode 4 as well to obtain the desired results:

```
audio/x-raw-int,rate=44100,channels=2 ! lame name=enc mode=0 quality=0 vbr=4 vbr-quality=0 ! xingmux ! id3v2mux
```