# How to burn an audio master cd?

Tags: cd, burning, audio-recording

**What I do:**

I record and mix audio using [Ardour](https://ardour.org/) or [Harrison Mixbus](http://harrisonconsoles.com/site/mixbus.html). Most of the time now, I don't need to create an master audio cd: bands ans artists are happy enough with audio files. Providing them with high quality .wav files, and some mp3 or .aac is enough nowadays.

However, for a new project, I will have to do again a master audio cd. It is used as a reference to press audio cd.

**The issue:**

In the past, with Ubuntu or Ubuntu Studio, I used gCDmaster, a GUI for [cdrdao](http://cdrdao.sourceforge.net/). It is not available anymore in repositories, for a long time.

With Ardour or Mixbus, I can export one long .wav file and the .toc description file.

**So I am looking for a burning software that:**

- can import one long .wav file, or many short .wav files
- can import .toc or .cue files for tracks information
- can edit and save tracks informations (e.g: cd text)
- can burn the cd at lowest speed possible for the burner (less errors possible)

Any idea ?

(Brasero and k3b can not do that)

Comment: did you try `k3b` ?

Comment: will k3b install al lot of dependencies, like other KDE applications ?

Comment: not much look at my answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/588384/how-to-configure-soundjuicer-mysterious-mp3-encoding-settings/591597#591597 it referes to different question but to audio also.

Comment: this is not at all the same kind of issue...

Comment: +1 to K3b. The dependencies will not cause a problem and IMO K3b has been the most reliable.

Comment: @ttoine don't pay much attention to issue though as I said it referes to different one but `k3b` does what it should. :) that answer just contain all the needed packages to install.

Comment: tested, k3b is just an equivalent of Brasero, but for KDE. Good to burn an audio cd with many tracks or files. Not for making a master cd. And k3b needs more than 40Mb of dependencies, including many KDE libs.

Comment: why don't you install gcdmaster then?

Comment: read my question. not available anymore in repositories, not maintained anymore.

Comment: yeah my bad I see that you can manually do so if it work https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+package/gcdmaster

Comment: It looks like it would be possible to rebuild the gCDmaster package for 12.04 fairly easily, later releases may need to borrow some bits from 12.04. Note if it is a GUI for `cdrdao` you probably just use that...

Comment: It could be possible to build from source on 14.04 x64 (my current ubuntu box) if the MP3 and OGG support things get satisfied - see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/548665/toc2mp3-converting-toc-files-to-mp3-using-cdrdao). For building stuff it may help to install `build-essential` `fakeroot` & `devscripts`, as well as `libgtkmm-2.4-dev` for dependices. `checking for LIBGUIMM2... no` seems to be the biggest issue to deal with

Comment: Found issue with needing http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libs/libgnome-vfsmm-2.6-1c2a but need a build number less than 2.22... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell giving up for now :(

Comment: by the way, the aim is to burn high quality audio. So I don't need ogg or mp3 support. Wave only is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep on using **cdrdao**, without a GUI, from the command line.
In theory, it should be as simple as:

```
cdrdao write album-master.toc
```

but in practice, it turned out to be a bit more complicated than that. Here's what I had to do:

- **simulate** - Before anything else, let's use `simulate` instead of `write`. It'll avoid ruining a CDr if an error occurs. We'll revert back to `write` once a simulation has completed with success.
- **device** - Next, it can't hurt to specify which drive you want to use. `cdrdao scanbus` will list your drive(s) address(es). I wanted to use `/dev/sr0` so added this to the command: `--device /dev/sr0`
- **driver** - By default cdrdao uses the `generic-mmc` driver, and by default this driver *doesn't write* **CD-TEXT**. We have to specifically state that we want to also burn the text by setting the driver bit to `0x10` like this: `--driver generic-mmc:0x10`
- **speed** - I haven't used that option as cdrdao detects the speed of the drive automatically, but if you want you can add `--speed 4` to the command to force your drive to write at that speed (mine won't go below 16).

So now the command looks more like this:

```
cdrdao simulate --device /dev/sr0 --driver generic-mmc:0x10 album-master.toc
```

- **Ardour's TOC** - cdrdao can be a bit sniffy with the toc files generated by Ardour(5):

  - If you used the *Performer* field in **any** of Ardour's *CD markers*, then it has to be filled in for **every** track, otherwise cdrdao fails.
  - We have to open the toc file in a text editor to manually edit the `TITLE` and `PERFORMER` of the whole cd, located in the first `CD_TEXT` block (but do not add a `COMPOSER` entry there or cdrdao will fail).
  - Whilst we're here, Ardour hardcodes the wav file location which means that if we ever move the .wav and .toc files to a different folder/device, cdrdao will not find the .wav file and fail. So it's worth doing a quick search-and-replace-all:
    `FILE "/home/xxxxx/ardour/album-master/export/album-master.wav"`
    `FILE "album-master.wav"`

If the simulation now runs successfully, you can replace `simulate` by `write` and be on your way. In my case I had to work around a couple more bugs:

- **Bugs**

  - For some reason when opening a session, Ardour seems to convert my first `CD marker` to a `Location marker`, which then messes up the exported TOC file. So I have to fix that every time before exporting.
  - I kept the most annoying/weird bug for last. **cdrdao** kept failing with this error:
    `ERROR: Cannot set write parameters mode page.`
    and telling me to `Please try to use the 'generic-mmc-raw' driver`.
    But changing the command to `--driver generic-mmc-raw` would also fail, this time with a different error:
    `ERROR: Write data failed.`
    Then sometimes, seemingly at random, everything would work perfectly and I could write as many cds as I wanted.
    Eventually I worked it out: first run the command *once* with `--driver generic-mmc-raw`, let it fail with the `Write data failed` error, and *after that* the command with `--driver generic-mmc:0x10` works fine. Go figure...